# Preg match and Preg replace specific format

Tags: php, regex

I need help with preg match/replace forma i really cant understand how its working and what each element doing.

So far I have this:

```
$username = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $_POST['uname']);
if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,12}+$/u', $username))
{ 
    $username =  trim(strip_tags(ucfirst($purifier->purify(@$_POST["uname"]))));
}
else
{
    $message['uname']='wrong username input';
}
```

And for utf8(hebrew language) i got this:

```
if(preg_match("/^[\p{Hebrew} a-zA-Z0-9]{2,10}+$/u", $_POST['fname']))
{
    //
}
```

which is working perfect, but I don't want to allow Hebrew on username just English.

I tried to play with that in multiple combinations, I tried to change but no success, and I did research on StackOverflow and Google but can't make it like I want I don't understand.
I used a RegEx site to and tried to build but with no success.

So until now I got this :

User can put 5-12 letters/numbers no special characters.

What i want is :

- Can enter between 5-12 letters/numbers no special charcaters - i
  already have it.
- Allow whitespaces
- `preg_match` if no mixed language's like E.G: $username = שדגדשsdsd; <- not allowed mixed languages.

And `preg_replace` to:

- Replace white spaces to nothing (remove white spaces) i have this but i dont know if it correct:

`$username = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $_POST['uname']);`

Also, I am using UTF-8 language .

**EDIT:**

With help of hwnd ,  i make it to work like i want the latest code:

```
     if(preg_match('/^[\p{Hebrew}]{2,10}|[a-zA-Z]{2,10}$/u', $_POST['fname']) &&  preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]{2,10}|[\p{Hebrew}]{2,10}$/u', $_POST['fname']))
        {
                     $message = 'valid';
        }else{

          $message = 'Invalid';
        }
```

**Solved**,Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure if your allowing whitespace in the username, you can suffice with just a space character but to be safe use `\s` which matches whitespace (`\n`, `\r`, `\t`, `\f`, and `" "`), for that you can just add that inside of your character class `[]`

```
if (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]{5,12}+$/u', $username)) { ...
```

And you can leave your `preg_replace()` function as is...

**Update**: To match different characters, but not mixed you could try the following:

```
$user = 'hwדגדשרביd';   // "invalid"
$user = 'fooo';         //  "valid"
$user = 'שדגדשרביב';   //  "valid"

if (preg_match('/^[\p{Hebrew}]{2,10}|[a-zA-Z]{2,10}$/u', $user)) {
  echo "valid";
} else {
  echo "invalid";
}
```

Comment: Yea . E.G : u used username = hwnd - its ok. u used username = רביב - its ok. but if you used username = hwרב - its not allowed not mixed languges

Comment: ok , i tryed it and its not good its always false, even if i mix and even if i dont mix, i tryed to fix it with rubular.com , but no succses can you see why? and also edit your answer with the latest code .

Answer (score 1):

Your `preg_replace` for removing whitespace from the username is fine.

To allow only English letters, digits and whitespace in the username, use this:

```
if (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]{5,12}+$/u', $username)) {
    # $username is OK
}
else {
    # $username is not OK
}
```

Comment: I dont want to allow only english , i want to not allow mixed language at username like english and spanish just for example any idea?